# VueJS treat computed value as raw HTML without requiring div wrapper

Tags: vuejs2

In Vue2, you can treat a value as HTML by wrapping it in a

```
<div v-html="computedValue"/>
```

However that adds an extra <div> tag around every element, whether or not it is required.  What I'd like to do is optionally treat a value as raw HTML without requiring the extra div tag if it is non-html text.

The only way I can think of doing it right now requires adding 2 additional computed properties, and calculating the value multiple times:

```
<div v-if="containsHtml" v-html="computedValue"/>{{nonHtmlValue}}
```

The component

```
Vue.component("datatable-cell", {
    template: `
        <td>{{computedValue}}</td>
        <!-- above is ideal  I'm trying to avoid 
        <td><div v-if="containsHtml" v-html="computedValue"/>{{nonHtmlValue}}</td>
         -->
    `,
    props: ["row","column"],
    computed: {
        containsHtml: function(){
            return this.computedValue != null && this.computedValue.charAt[0] == "<";
        },
        nonHtmlValue: function(){
           if(this.containsHtml) return "";
           return this.computedValue;
        },
        computedValue: function(){
            if(this.column.template){
                var templateValue = this.column.template(this.row);
                if(isSafeMarkup(templateValue)){
                    //Treat as HTML - how????
                    return templateValue;
                }else{
                    //Escape and treat as text.  This already works
                    return templateValue;
                }
            }else{
                return this.row[column.name];
            }
        }
})
```